# DataTable to nested JSON using Javascript serializer in C#

Tags: c#, .net, json, datatable, javascriptserializer

I'm converting a Data Table rows into a `JSON` string. Using a Javascript serializer I have generated a normal `JSON` string. How can we generated it as Nested string.

**Current Json output**

```
{  
   "PatientId":"32424",
   "CustomerId":"XXXX",
   "Name":"DiastolicBloodPressure",
   "Value":89,
   "Unit":"mmHg",
   "MinValue":50,
   "MaxValue":90,
   "SessionElementResponseText":null
}
```

**Expected**

```
{  
   "PatientId":"32424",
   "CustomerId":"XXXX",
   "VitalThreshold":{  
      "Name":"DiastolicBloodPressure",
      "Value":89,
      "Unit":"mmHg",
      "MinValue":50,
      "MaxValue":90
   },
   "SessionElementResponseText":null
}
```

**Code**

```
public static string DataTableToJSON(DataTable table)
{
    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
    Dictionary<string, object> row;
    foreach(DataRow dr in table.Rows)
    {
        row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        foreach(DataColumn col in table.Columns)
        {
            if(col.ColumnName.Equals("Name"))
            {
                //Trying here
            }
            row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
        }
        rows.Add(row);
    }
    serializer.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
    return serializer.Serialize(rows);
}
```

Comment: What is the data in the DataTable looks alike?

Comment: @RawitasKrungkaew - The DataTable looks like the `Current Json output `shown above. The column names of the Data Table are PatientId | CustomerId | Name | Value | Unit | MinValue | MaxValue | SessionElementResponseText

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you have to add one condition to buffer the inner row. Then, at the end of the loop add the "inner row" into the main row.

```
    public static string DataTableToJSON(DataTable table)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
        Dictionary<string, object> row;
        var innerList = new string[] { "Name", "Value", "Unit", "MinValue", "MaxValue" };
        var innerRow = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
        {
            row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
            {
                if (innerList.Contains(col.ColumnName))
                {
                    innerRow.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
                }
                else
                {
                    row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
                }

            }
            row.Add("VitalThreshold", innerRow);
            rows.Add(row);
        }
        serializer.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
        return serializer.Serialize(rows);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static string DataTableToJSON(DataTable table)
{
    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
    string[] keys = new string[] { "Name", "Value", "Unit", "MinValue", "MaxValue" };
    foreach(DataRow dr in table.Rows)
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        foreach(DataColumn col in table.Columns)
        {
            if(keys.Contains(col.ColumnName)) dict.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
            else row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
        }
        row.Add("VitalThreshold", dict);
        rows.Add(row);
    }
    serializer.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
    return serializer.Serialize(rows);
}
```